# C# time.sleep not working as expected for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, while-loop

So this algorithm should flash the word finished in 1 second intervals 3 times but it just freezes for 5 seconds instead. Any ideas?

```
bool appear = false;
int i = 0;
while (i < 5)
{
    i++;
    if (appear == false)
    {
        appear = true;
        Finished_label.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        appear = false;
        Finished_label.Visible = false;
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

*Edit I am writing this in C# Visual Studio Windows Forms Application

Comment: Please clarify what ui framework you're using.

Comment: My guess is you are trying to do this from the UI thread so `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` freezes your UI. You need to use [`async/await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: hi,

you are freezing the ui thread, you should allow to process
basically the rendering is done only at the end of your loop

Comment: If it's WPF, you're blocking the UI thread for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Thread.Sleep() blocks the UI thread, so you don't see the changes. You could use

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```